# ¿Cómo comunicar dos componentes de angular mediante signals?

Tags: angular, typescript, componentes, signals

¿Cómo intercambiar información entre componentes utilizando un `BehaviorSubject` en un servicio en Angular?

Primero, crearemos un servicio llamado `DataService` que contendrá un `BehaviorSubject` para compartir datos entre componentes.

```js
// data.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private datosCompartidos = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Datos iniciales');

  obtenerDatosCompartidos() {
    return this.datosCompartidos.asObservable();
  }

  actualizarDatos(datos: string) {
    this.datosCompartidos.next(datos);
  }
}
```

En este servicio, hemos utilizado un `BehaviorSubject` llamado `datosCompartidos` para almacenar los datos que deseamos compartir entre componentes. También hemos expuesto un método `obtenerDatosCompartidos()` que otros componentes pueden utilizar para suscribirse y recibir actualizaciones.

A continuación, crearemos dos componentes: uno para enviar datos al servicio y otro para recibirlos.

```js
// sender.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sender',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Componente Emisor</h2>
      <input [(ngModel)]="nuevosDatos" placeholder="Ingrese nuevos datos" />
      <button (click)="enviarDatos()">Enviar Datos</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class SenderComponent {
  nuevosDatos = '';

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  enviarDatos() {
    this.dataService.actualizarDatos(this.nuevosDatos);
  }
}
```

```js
// receiver.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-receiver',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Componente Receptor</h2>
      <p>Datos Recibidos: {{ datosRecibidos }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ReceiverComponent implements OnInit {
  datosRecibidos = 'Esperando datos...';

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.obtenerDatosCompartidos().subscribe((datos) => {
      this.datosRecibidos = datos;
    });
  }
}
```

En el componente `Sender`, hemos creado un método `enviarDatos()` que utiliza el servicio `DataService` para actualizar los datos compartidos cuando se hace clic en el botón.

En el componente `Receiver`, nos suscribimos al observable que obtenemos del método `obtenerDatosCompartidos()` del servicio `DataService`. Cuando llegan nuevos datos, actualizamos la propiedad `datosRecibidos` para reflejarlos en la plantilla.

Asegúrate de agregar estos componentes y el servicio al módulo correspondiente de la misma manera que se hizo en el ejemplo anterior.

Con esta configuración, puedes ingresar datos en el componente `Sender` y ver cómo se actualizan automáticamente en el componente `Receiver` gracias al uso de `BehaviorSubject` y observables.

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo hacer este mismo ejemplo usando signals?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "signals"?

Comment: En Angular 16 añadieron la funcionalidad de signals. Por lo que entiendo de los signals se utilizan muy parecidos a los `useState` de React

Comment: En cuanto a la pregunta. https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2023/06/23/introduccion-a-signals-en-angular-16/

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de receiverComponent, al ser un datos de lectura, te recomiendo que uses computed en lugar de acceder directamente a un signal. Si necesitas ayuda me dices ;)

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  datosCompartidos = signal<string>('Datos iniciales...');
}
```

sender.component.ts

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sender',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Componente Emisor</h2>
      <input [(ngModel)]="nuevosDatos" placeholder="Ingrese nuevos datos" />
      <button (click)="enviarDatos()">Enviar Datos</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class SenderComponent {
  nuevosDatos = '';

  private dataService = inject(DataService)

  enviarDatos() {
    this.dataService.datosCompartidos.set(this.nuevosDatos);
  }
}
```

receiver.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-receiver',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Componente Receptor</h2>
      <p>Datos Recibidos: {{ datosRecibidos() }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ReceiverComponent {    
  private dataService = inject(DataService)
  datosRecibidos = this.dataService.datosCompartidos;
}
```